# Last rite ritual Mantras for non-humans

Tags: vedas, rituals, dharma-shastras, death, garuda-purana

Here is the situation. Assuming Aliens exist & they visit earth. In that process one of them dies. Are there any scriptural notes on such situations as to how the body needs to be cremated? And what mantras to utter? Clearly, none of the mantras, the Gothras are applicable. But, my question is are there any Vedic sources that talk about for e.g Yaksha, Gandharva or such extra terrestrial last rites? thanks

Comment: your question amounts to scientific speculation as it has not been shown that any aliens have visited, much less died, on earth.

Comment: Lord did last rite for Jatayu brid and gave him moksha.. This shows even animals of highest order which done seva to lord like Gajendra elephant can be done last rite..

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - he means deva, asura, rakshasa, gandharva. Not the english word alien. there is plenty of evidence of the former visiting earth.